# Bias T for modulation of VCSEL laserdiode

Tags: photodiode, modulation, bias

For my project, I would like to design a Bias Tee for a VCSEL laserdiode, because a modulation is required. The bandwidth is 20 KHz - 10 MHz. My steps are shown below:

[image: Summary]

As a reference, I have used the formulas of Bias t from wikipedia and [this site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9325/i-need-to-design-a-bias-t-circuit-for-a-diode-laser-help-choosing-component-va).

The RF input of the bias tee is a RF input voltage which is converted to an AC-current by using a resistor (R1) in series with a capacitor. The DC input is just an input for the DC-current as it is directly connected to a laser driver with a limiting resistor (R2). However, I have some doubts with regard to choosing inductors due to the SFR (Self resonance frequency), the maximum frequency where an inductor still behaves as an inductor, is relatively difficult to search for with 2-3 times higher than the maximum frequency.

Thus, I would like to know whether these steps(in image) are correct and second, do you have tips for me to choose inductors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The RF input of the bias tee is a RF input voltage which is converted to an AC-current by using a resistor (R1) in series with a capacitor.

Given the fairly high impedance of your VCSEL, you shouldn't need any external resistance to convert voltage to current.

You may want to use a 50 ohm source if your traces are long enough to worry about impedance matching effects at the two ends.

> However, I have some doubts with regard to choosing inductors due to the SFR (Self resonance frequency), ... is relatively difficult to search for with 2-3 times higher than the maximum frequency.

Nonetheless you have to search for it. You will spend some time going over the product selection tables at the various inductor manufacturers.

> do you have tips for me to choose inductors?

You might have to use 2 or 3 inductors in series. A low-value inductor connected to the RF trace to block high frequency signals, and progressively higher-value inductors in series to block lower frequency signals.

You will want to use a simulator to work out how the parasitics of these inductors interact with the other inductors. You might find it helpful to add moderate-value (100-1000 ohm) resistors in parallel with some of the larger inductors to "dequeue" the resonances. Rarely, a capacitor to ground from one of the connection points between inductors, or in parallel with one of the inductors, can help smooth out the response (but more often it creates inconvenient new resonances).

One other thing: 1:100 impedance ratio for the capacitor is pretty conservative for something like this. 1:50 or 1:20 will probably work quite well...letting you stick to a 10 uF value, which can be had in an 0402 package.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. If I would simulate the bias tee with laser diode, is it true that a laserdiode is nothing else than a resistor with a capacitor in parallel (laser diode model) for simulation?